# Regarding passing file as env variable in docker container

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to start a VGS satellite container as mentioned [here](https://github.com/verygoodsecurity/vgs-satellite#using-the-docker-image)

But I also need to pass a environment variable `SATELLITE_ROUTES_PATH`, which is also a filepath in local data folder.

```
docker run --rm -v data:/data -p 8089:8089 -p 9098:9098 -p 9099:9099 -e SATELLITE_ROUTES_PATH=/data/httbin.yml verygood/satellite     
Usage: app.py [OPTIONS]
Try 'app.py --help' for help.

Error: Invalid value for '--routes-path': File '/data/httbin.yml' does not exist.
```

How to resolve this issue, where I want to pass a VGS file while running container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bind a volume using docker, the host directory path cannot be relative:

This won't work:

```
-v data:/data
```

Change to a absolute path like `-v ~/Downloads/data:/data` or `-v /home/user/Downloads/data:/data`

If still you see the same error, make sure the file `httbin.yml` exists in out `data` folder

---

Note: The `-v` flag is very flexible. It can bindmount or name a volume with just a slight adjustment in syntax. If the first argument begins with a `/` or `~/`, you’re creating a bindmount. **Remove that, and you’re naming the volume.**

- `-v /path:/path/in/container` mounts the host directory, `/path` at the
  `/path/in/container`
- `-v path:/path/in/container` creates a volume named `path` with no relationship to the host.